# How can I call my second function after my first function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two functions and two GUI.
I cannot get them to work after each other.
first, I want to open my browse GUI then editing GUI.
help me out, please.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
window = Tk()
def fileme():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilenames(filetypes=[("Text file","*.txt")])
    print(file_path)
    window.withdraw()
    with open(file_path[0]) as f:
        f_contents = f.read()
        b=(f_contents)
        print(b)
window.title('Edit and save text files by Ali')
frame = Frame(window)
btn = Button(frame, text = 'Browse', command= fileme)
btn.pack(side = RIGHT , padx =55)
frame.pack(padx=100,pady = 30)

root=Tk()
x=filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text file","*.txt")])
T=Text(root,state='normal', height=20, width=70)
T.pack()
T.insert(END, open(x).read())
def save():
    b = T.get('1.0', END)
    f = open(x, 'wt')
    f.write(b)
    f.close()
btn= Button(root, text='Save', command=save)
btn.pack(side = RIGHT , padx =55)
window.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is `browse` and `edit` in your gui?

Comment: browse is by function fileme and edit =x which has the function save at the end / to say it in another word: I created a browse gui and a text gui , these two should work together first i need to browse the files using a button then open my text files in order to edit them. finally with a  (save) button it would be done.

Comment: Your objective seems confusing

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Comment: You should use `Tk()` only once. For creating more windows you should use `Toplevel`.

Comment: You should not use `Tk()` more than once if you need more than one window then use `Toplevel()`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
Here is an answer to this type of questions. 
hope to be useful for anyone who is learning programming.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
window=Tk()
def x():
    x=filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text file","*.txt")])
    T = Text(window, state='normal', height=20, width=70)
    T.pack()
    T.insert(END, open(x).read())

    def save():
        b = T.get('1.0', END)
        f = open(x, 'wt')
        f.write(b)
        f.close()
    btn1 = Button(window, text='Save', command=save)
    btn1.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=55)
window.title('Edit and save text files by Ali')
frame = Frame(window)
btn = Button(frame, text = 'Browse', command= x)
btn.pack(side = RIGHT , padx =55)
frame.pack(padx=100,pady = 30)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

@Epiphnac In your solution both the browser window and the text editor open in the same `window`. I think my solution is a little bit better than that.

I have put the editor inside a new window using `Toplevel`.
Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

window = tk.Tk()


def editor():
    x = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text file", "*.txt")])
    new_window = tk.Toplevel()
    t = tk.Text(new_window, state='normal', height=20, width=70)
    t.pack()
    t.insert(tk.END, open(x).read())

    def save():
        b = t.get('1.0', tk.END)
        f = open(x, 'wt')
        f.write(b)
        f.close()
    btn1 = tk.Button(new_window, text='Save', command=save)
    btn1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=55)


window.title('Edit and save text files by Ali')
frame = tk.Frame(window)
btn = tk.Button(frame, text='Browse', command=editor)
btn.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=55)
frame.pack(padx=100, pady=30)

window.mainloop()
```